# A 'url' property or function must be specified error in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am trying to make a small app to learn how Backbone works. I took example app from source called [Todo](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html). I have created my app from scratch using snippets from Todo app. I think these apps look very similar but for some reason I can't make work some things that work fine in the example app. I get an error:

```
A 'url' property or function must be specified
```

The other problem is that I can't make this code from the example work:

```
this.model.bind('change', this.render);
```

It says there is no such a function as bind. I checked all libraries versions and code and can't realize what I do wrong. What can I do about this?

Comment: Without more of your code, it's hard to interpret the problem with the URL error.  The most obvious, to me, is that it's trying to fetch something from a back-end server and it needs a URL for that on construction, but you haven't provided one.  For the second error, is your model object a backbone model?  Put a "console.log(this.model)" on the line above it, look at it in Firebug, and figure out if it has a bind property.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The TODO example is relying on localStorage thus it does not define a url (as it is local). However, when you use the default Backbone.sync implementation, you need to define a url attribute on your collections and models (it can be either static or a function). Not doing so results in the error you got.

As for the this.model.bind, I guess you lost the reference to your model somehow. Two things: *this* is not what you think it is or *this.model* is not defined. Post more code to have complete answers.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I will check these now and will let you know if I solve the issues. Thanks.

Comment: this contradicts the backbone documentation: "Generates URLs of the form: "/[collection.url]/[id]", falling back to "/[urlRoot]/id" if the model is not part of a collection."

Answer (score 3):

The collection attempts to load a bunch of models from json output at the URL:

```
window.MyList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyModel,
  url: 'someurl.json', // load a bunch of json objects into models.
});
```

If that URL points to a json output of your models, you're good to go.

You can also override the way a collection makes restful call back to your server to support legacy servers or a local storage adapter: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to collection property url worked for me

```
todoList.url = "/GetData/GetTodo";
```